# Would the root test be applied to determine if this series converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have this problem, that appears as if the root test would apply, however I'm not sure.

The problem reads: Determine whether this series converges or diverges

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ne^{-.02n}$$

If it's not the root test, which other test would be applied for this? These limits just confuse me, because I feel like there are many tests that I could run, but I'm not quite sure which one would be the most appropriate to run.

Comment: This is your third recent question asking which test to use to decide whether a series converges. The general answer to these questions is "try the ones you know and see which work". After a while you will develop some intuitions that will lead you to a useful test quickly.

Comment: @EthanBolker I am verifying if this is the proper test to use. I'm still trying to learn how these tests are conducted and asking about it helps me learn.

Comment: If you want help with your work you should [edit] the question to show us that work. Let us see how you tried to apply the root test, or other tests, and what you were able to conclude and where in particular you are stuck. You will learn a lot more that way than if someone here just tells you why the series converges, or doesn't.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: @robjohn I am mainly asking about which test would be the best to use in order to find if the series converges or diverges.

Comment: Exponential always wins over a polynomial. Always. Because the power in the exponent is negative, the series will converge eventually.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley therefore, would the root test be valid?

Comment: @AdanVivero I wouldn't use a root test. It's always a rule of thumb that... log < poly < exponent < factorial < power tower. Examples of each type are: log = $\ln(x)$, poly = $x^3-x^2+x+48$, exponent = $5^x$, factorial = $x!$, and power tower = $x^x$.

Comment: @AdanVivero: Try the various tests. In many cases, more than one test will apply. You just need to try them. The experience of using the tests will give insight the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use the ratio test, this will probably work better!

Reminder: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| =p$$

If $p<1$ the series converges by the ratio test and if $p>1$ the series diverges by the ratio test.

Comment: Why would the root test not work on this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would or would not, however the ratio test just seems easier as the powers tend to cancel more easily. Can you try this?

Comment: Understanding, and yes I believe you. I'm just trying to verify which test to use, since I am still not the best understanding those.

Comment: Explanations help out here.

Comment: There’s no real way to see, it’s just what you think, the ratio test is usually helpful when there are powers to the N or factorial. Root test could be Abit annoying because of the root n at the start....

Comment: @Jamesodare: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$ is not much more complicated than $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}n=1$, and in any case, both are useful and should be known.

Comment: @AdanVivero If the ration test works, then so will the root test. But in this example, the ratio test is just much easier to use.